# What does pushd %~dp0 in .cmd file means? I understand %~dp0 means it indicates a drive letter

Tags: windows, batch-file

What does `pushd %~dp0` in `.cmd` file means? I understand that  `%~dp0` means it indicates a drive letter. What does `pushd` indicate?.

Comment: Also see [docs for pushd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd)

Answer (score 16):

Save the current directory on a stack and change to `%~dp0` which is the drive-and-path of the "0'th" command-line parameter (which is the command itself) so the destination path to be set is the drive/path of the batch file to be executed.

To return to the original path, you need a `popd`